# search text within a predetermined set of patents

Tags: search, text

Do you know of any patent search tool that allows you to search text within a predetermined set of patents? preferably free tool.

Or alternatively, somewhere I can download the text of the set of patents I'm interested so that I can do local searches? Notice I have the pdf documents for these patents, downloaded from google patents, however these are scans with not too much quality -- and a local OCR doesn't seem to be able to get the correct text.

Comment: It may depend on how big your search set is. Are you contemplating a more sophistiated search than what you can accomplish by refining search results at the USPTO search site?

Comment: I'm writing my first patent and I just wanted to see how certain terms are used within a set of prior art patents. So if I could do free text searches on this set it would be fantastic. Set size is around 50 patents.

Comment: If you search this forum, you will find some different views on drafting your own patent.  Feel free to ask additional questions here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on Yorick's answer - I do not often recommend the USPTO search tools but this is a good use for them as long as you are not looking anything pre-1976. You can definitely download text using that URL at the USPTO and do a local search. Or a boolean search like [PN/(7,849,039  OR  7,890,523  OR 7,895,230  OR 7,933,904  OR 7,941,428  OR 7,970,822) AND locate] on the USPTO site (under Advanced) would look for "locate" in all of the listed "OR'd" patents and return a list of only the patents with that text. 
[image: Search result screen shot]. Note that to get published U.S. applications the search would need to be re-run. Patents and Publications are not searchable at one place.

Comment: Thanks for the info. For some reason my search PN/(20120212405 OR 20110285810) AND SPEC/"motion sensors" is not working. In fact I haven't been able to find the patents by number so I'm not sure if I'm using the right number or they just don't have these particular patents

Comment: The Uspto search separates applications and granted patents. The numbers in your example are published applications (they start with a year). The URL is http://appft1.uspto.gov/netahtml/PTO/search-bool.html and the field is DN for document number vs PN

Answer (score 1):

Free boolean search tool, can refine search results:

http://patft.uspto.gov/netahtml/PTO/search-bool.html

Answer (score 1):

[Pattools](http://www.pattools.com) is nice. I don't know if it has the exact features you are looking for, but it does allow you to give a list of patents. It returns the specifications and claims for those patents in a much nicer format than the PDF. It also allows you to download the PDF.